# Understanding shorthand C++

Tags: c++, shorthand

I have this code in my C++ book, and I am unsure what this code means:

```
for ( ; counter < fooCnt &&
        (toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x) == string::npos)
      ; counter++);
```

This is all on one line, Is there another way this code could be written? I do not understand also why is there a ";" before a variable in the beginning of the for loop....

Comment: It means the author is messing with you. ;-)

Comment: I'm sure you are familiar with `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` format.  As you see there are 2 `;` there.  In your example, you simply skip the variable portion.

Answer (score 5):

`clause 1` in a for-loop is optional. It says to loop until `array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x)` is not equal to `string::npos` or `counter >= fooCnt`

`&&` is the short-circuit AND operator. Go back to your truth tables if your forgot this part.

`counter < fooCnt && (toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x)==string::npos)` is expression-2 and `counter++` is expression-3

`counter` is incremented thusly.

in [6.8.5.3](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.8.5.3.html) of the C standard:

> 1774 The statement
>
> ```
>     for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows:
>
> 1775 The expression >expression-2 is the controlling expression that
>   is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>
> 1776 The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression
>   after each execution of the loop body.
>
> 1777 If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any 
>   identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the
>   entire loop, including the other two expressions;
>
> 1778 it is reached in the order of execution before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression.
>
> 1779 If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void
>   expression before the first evaluation of the controlling
>   expression.134)
>
> 1780 Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted.
>
> 1781 An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.

By the way, a for-loop can also be thought of like a while loop.

Comment: DeMorgan's theorem fail.  Actually, it loops until something is found **OR** `counter >= fooCnt`.

Answer (score 3):

You could write it like this

```
 int counter = 0;

 bool IsNotFound = (toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x)==string::npos);

 for(;counter < fooCnt && IsNotFound;counter++)
 {

   // do stuff
  //update IsNotFound for next iteration
  IsNotFound =(toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x) == string::npos);
 }
```

It will loop only if `IsNotFound` is true.

Comment: Better call that `IsNotFound`.  Also I think you have an off-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as

```
for ( counter = counter; counter < fooCnt; counter++ ) {
    if (toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x) != string::npos) break;
}
```

e.g. `counter` goes from its current value, increasing by 1, until `fooCnt`.  But if any of the titles are found, it stops early.

Comment: Isn't counter = counter redundant.. why not use `int i = counter` instead?

Comment: @0A0D: It is redundant, but it puts it into the recognizable form `for ( var = start; var < stop; var += step )`  As for why not `int i = counter`, it's because the original code leaves a useful value in `counter` corresponding to the found index.  If you introduce a new local `i`, then `counter` will be meaningless after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain this line. At first a for loop looks like this *for(init part; condition part; part for the next step)*. So the first ; means that the init part was skipped. Normally after the for statment is code which gets executed but in this case it was skipped with the colon.

in the condition check is this code:

```
counter<fooCnt && (toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x)==string::npos)
```

if the condition `counter<fooCnt` is true the folowing code will be executed:

```
toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x)==string::npos
```

at least after every loop the counter is increaded.

```
counter++
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's pretty ugly.  I would break it down a bit.

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < fooCnt; ++i) {
    auto lowcase = toLower(array[i].getFooTitle());
    if(lowcase.find(x) != string::npos) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you start with `int i = counter;` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: More than likely counter is 0 so this would work.. I can see your point.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, I made the assumption that `counter` was 0 before entering the loop.  I could be wrong.

Comment: BTW, this version is useless because you can't get to the important information (the index where the match occurred) outside the loop.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is true.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way this code could be written?

It might be clearer as

```
while (counter < fooCnt && 
       (toLower(array[counter].getFooTitle()).find(x)==string::npos)) 
{
    ++counter;
}
```

i.e. while we haven't reached the limit, *and* we haven't found `x`, move on to the next one. Equivalently, loop until we reach the limit *or* we find `x`.

> I do not understand also why is there a ";" before a variable in the beginning of the for loop

The `for` statement has three clauses, as in

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

The first declares and/or initialises variables to be used in the loop - it can be empty if, as here, you don't want any. The second is evaluated before each iteration to decide whether to continue - it can be empty if you always want to continue. The third is evaluated after each iteration - it can be empty if there's nothing to update between iterations.

Comment: Whats the difference between ++counter and counter++? I assume you increment until counter?

Comment: @user12074577: If, as here, you're not using the result of the expression, then there's no difference. I use `++counter` out of habit because, in some circumstances (but not here), it can be more efficient than `counter++`.